# Unresolved External Symbol in my Singleton Variable

Tags: c++, static, singleton, unresolved-external

I have been trying to implement a simple singleton, however I am getting a unresolved external:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static class Xeno::Engine * Xeno::Engine::m_instance" (?m_instance@Engine@Xeno@@0PAV12@A)
```

I looked around online for a while looking at examples on singleton classes, however I can't seem to find anything wrong with what I am trying to do.

---

Here's my header file:

```
#pragma once

namespace Xeno {

    class Engine
    {
    private:
        Engine();

        static Engine* m_instance;
    protected:
    public:
        ~Engine();

        static Engine* GetInstance()
        {
            if (m_instance == nullptr)
                m_instance = new Engine();

            return m_instance;
        }

        void TestFunc();
    };

}
```

And here's my cpp file:

```
#include "Engine.h"

namespace Xeno {

    Engine* Engine::m_instance = nullptr;

    Engine::Engine()
    {

    }

    Engine::~Engine()
    {

    }

    void Engine::TestFunc()
    {
    }

}
```

Comment: Is that the only unresolved symbol?

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes, that's the only one.

Comment: What compiler command are you using to link your program? Does it include the object that containes your static instance?

Comment: @Galik Oh, I had no idea that applied to functions as well. I put the definition of the GetInstance function inside the cpp file and it works now. Thank you :)

Comment: Your code is fine.

Comment: btw, I recommend looking at this method of creating singletons: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1008289/3807729